# Refer to a method through annotation

Tags: java

Recently I've thought about an issue where you have a method that does some sort of action but it should not be called directly but rather through another method that properly handles it.

So what I've been thinking to do is create an annotation that will have inside it the method to use instead, I.E:

```
 @NonDirectUsage(direct=MyClass.directMethod);
```

It would have to be similar to comments where you can link a reference, however, I want to use it that way so it could be used further through runtime and so on.

Example in a live code would be something like:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
@NonDirectUsage(direct=addToList)
public void add(T t) {
    super.add(t);
}

public void addToList(Integer i) {
   System.out.println("added integer properly: "+i);
   add(i);
}
```

Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: Why would you couple the usage of `add` in that way? `add` shouldn't know/care who calls it. What would you benefit from this?

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm pretty sure that's just an example of how it *could* be used, rather than a particularly *useful* way it could be used.

Comment: @ArtOfCode just as he said, it is obviously just an example.
But imagine having a list where its add has to do a few more things rather than just being added to the list. Yes, you could override the #add method but that would only solve one out of a few more usages of that system. Regardless of that, the question refers to if theres an option of linking a field (preferably method, constructor) through annotation.

Comment: Surely one way is using reflection and not using an actual reference but a string that is the method name.

Comment: @TyrantIst so basicly something like make `add(T t)` `private` and let the other method be the only one beeing left `public`? or something more like [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) provides?

Comment: "*have a method that does some sort of action but it should not be called directly but rather through another method that properly handles it.*" - This doesn't sound like a delegate to you? Access modifiers exist for limiting access. Features exist to solve problems - all I'm asking is which problem you're actually trying to solve. You shouldn't "create features" that don't actually solve any problems. If there's an actual problem, there's a good chance a solution exists. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that's why I asked

Comment: @VinceEmigh Basically, naturally there are default operations for certain classes, such as #add function for a List, and so on.
However, lets say we've had some sort of List<RandomClass>, which obviously has #add method but in this scenario, it is should not be called but still possible (for example, letting other developers in your repo know that they should not call that method directly but rather use another method that then calls it correctly).
Something like @ deprecated but that tells you what method to use instead. Sorry if my explanation is terrible

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes, you could have the reference as private but at the same time other methods that are actually suppose to be accessing it should be able to have access to it.

Comment: You can use `@Deprecated` with a custom message that will point them to the right method, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463271/java-function-annotation-help-use-deprecated

Comment: It's been discussed before that `List` violates [ISP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) by providing mutation methods (such as `add`), leaving no room for a proper read-only interface. Their solution was "*throw UnsupportedOperationException if someone tries to use a method they shouldn't*". But if this isn't enough for you, the *proper* way to go about this would be to use an interface that doesn't expose those methods. No need for hacks like the one you requested (which, chances are, probably could have been abused), this is what interfaces were designed for.

Comment: I won't write an answer, since people seem interested in getting an answer for this (**spoiler alert**: it won't work - annotations supports a limited amount of types for it's values, so you'd wind up needing to map the annotation value to the method, and there's no functional interface (for it's literal) that properly covers all method signatures without abstracting more than you'd probably want). If it's mandatory for you to hide `List#add`, you shouldn't be exposing the `List` interface, rather a type that delegates to a `List`, which only exposes the behavior you require to be exposed.

Comment: `@Deprecated` is the solution IMO like @tima pointed out.

Comment: Yet again you guys do not understand.
The point is not to say that a method ISN'T USABLE but rather SHOULDN'T BE USED. With that being said, deprecated has the purpose but I wanted to modify it to have a linking to the usable method instead, something like how {@link Class#method} works but being apart of the annotation and not a comment

Comment: @TyrantIst if your class cannot be used like the interface/super class, it should not implement/extend it but use composition instead - only expose what can be used (In other words, do not violate the [Liskov Sustitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if you can avoid it). If that is not possible, `@Deprecated` with a helpful message is the best you can do.

Comment: @Hulk LSP is only violated if the contract (specified via jdoc) doesn't specify the behavior. For example, Java's immutable `List` implementation doesn't violate LSP even though it has an `add` method, since `List#add` itself specifies that it may throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. So as long as he specifies that mutation methods may not be supported, LSP won't be violated by exposing them, even if their behavior differs, as the subtype would still abide the supertype's contract.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring, you could use AOP

e.g., your annotation would look something like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface NonDirectUsage {
}
```

Then you define an Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class NonDirectUsageAspect{

    @Around("@annotation(NonDirectUsage)")
    public Object addToList(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
       System.out.println("added integer properly: ");
       return null;
   }
}
```

do not forget to configure your code to handle aspects.

```
@Configuration  
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class NoDirectUsageConfig {}
```

I think you can do something similar if you are using JakartaEE.